# Installing package (xsane) without dependencies

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, aptitude, dependencies, xsane

I had to install the sane drivers with git due to my CanoScan 8800F to recognize the scanner. Scanning with "scanimage" works like a charm. But I'd prefer xsane to have a GUI. The problem is to install xsane without libsane dependencies. Otherwise it would install libsane and overwrite the git compiled sane-drivers. My scanner would not work then anymore. 
So I tried to install xsane by hand. But this seems to be a pain in the ass. First of all I downloaded the tar.gz sources (because there was no fitting version 0.996 as deb package). Secondly I tried to compile but I wasn't able to do a "make" because "SANE_CAP_ALWAYS_SETTABLE" wasn't defined in the code so it lead to a compile error. Then I found a patch but the patch didn't work either (Hunk #1 failed at ...**). After that I corrected the code by myself (I looked into the created "difference" file created by the patch command and looked for what I have to edit). "make" was able to compile then. When I was finished I created a deb package with "checkinstall -D make". At the end I installed the deb package with dpkg -i, but there doesn't seem to be any executable in /usr/bin or anywhere else, argh.

All I want to do is installing xsane without the dependencies of libsane (because I already have them, but apt doesn't know it). Is that anyhow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt-get source xsane then tweak the dependencies in the debian folder. and rebuild the .deb

this will fix the issue but you should also change the version to crazy high so upgrades don't blow out your git install later.

Comment: alternately you could make an empty libsane package

Comment: Where do I get a dep with apt-get source xsane? I already tried that but I get tar.gz files.

Comment: go to an empty folder and do it, it generates the tar.gz stuff and a folder.  go into the folder and look for the debian dir.(if it doesn't create the dir you have to extract the tar.gz)

Comment: Now I know what you mean. xsane can start now but now it can't access the scanner although it is recognized. This is getting really annoying. However, questions is answered.

Comment: By the way: Creating a rule /etc/udev/rules.d/50-libsane.rules with the content (in my case)

#Canon 8800F

SYSFS{idVendor}=="04a9",SYSFS{idProduct}=="1901",MODE="0666",GROUP="users"

..does the job.