# How to tell apt that dependencies are resolved manually?

Tags: package-management, apt

Let's say there is a software I don't want to install through `apt`, but manually. (TeXLive, because I want to use the 2011 release and `apt` only has the 2009 version.)

Let's say there is *another* software I'd like to install through `apt`, which however *depends* on the first software. (Vim LaTeXSuite, as it's a pain to install manually for system-wide use.)

Per default, `apt` doesn't "see" the first software, and proceeds to install lots of unneeded and unwelcome cruft (i.e. TeXLive 2009) just to satisfy the dependency metadata.

How can I either:

- Tell `apt` that a given package (e.g. `texlive`) *is* installed for all practical purposes, and that it shouldn't be installed as dependency of some other package?
- Tell `apt` to install a given package (e.g. `vim-latexsuite`) without bothering about its dependencies?

I've sifted through various `apt`-related manpages and came up empty, and also found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/195131/installing-package-xsane-without-dependencies) on this site but feel that there *has* to be a less hackish way to do this, no?

(From my Gentoo times, I remember `emerge --inject` and `/etc/portage/package.provides`, and am basically looking for the `apt` equivalents.)

Comment: TeX Live 2011 has been added to Debian Sid recently, so it should propagate sooner or later to Mint as well (but Ubuntu 12.04 "missed" it, so not earlier than the end of October with Ubuntu 12.10). If you are really adventurous you could perhaps grab the packages from Debian Sid, but since in this case it concerns *a lot* of packages, it's probably not a good solution. There is a PPA at https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa set up (see [this bug report in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521)) that you perhaps can use in Mint as well.

Comment: I've had a similar problem described here: [Ignoring specific unmet dependencies with aptitude? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/408696/ignoring-specific-unmet-dependencies-with-aptitude); also, there's a nice explanation here: [How can I install a package without installing its dependencies? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55244/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-its-dependencies/55248#55248)

Comment: No-comment downvote three years later... care to explain?

Comment: @DevSolar: Seems like someone serial-downvoted the question and both answers three years after-the-fact, without clarifying why. Best to just shrug and move on, I guess :-) .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the `equivs` package to generate meta-packages that provide these dependencies, and then use `dpkg` to install these packages.

Installing `equivs` and reading its documentation should be enough, but [this guide for Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726317) is quite extensive and should apply to other APT systems as well.

---

Also, if you feel that a package should be able to be installed without the specified dependency, you should file a bug against the package, explaining the case where the dependency is not needed.

[In this case](http://packages.debian.org/sid/vim-latexsuite), `texlive-base-bin` seems to only be "Recommended" and not a "Dependency" in the base Debian distribution at least (probably in part since `texlive` is such an enormous package), but because it is common to install upstream TeX Live on Debian since the distribution version often lags behind greatly (for the reason that the package is such a beast that it often can't be packaged without substantial work, which is mostly done by one or a few persons, who claim they have lives beside Debian), the `equivs` trick is often used with TeX Live (wow, that sentence got out of hand :-) ).

---

*Addition*: For more detailed instructions for those looking to install TeXLive outside of the package system, [these instructions on TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/38804) are more extensive and will most likely continue to be kept updated. They also include more explicit instructions regarding the `equivs` step.

Comment: I don't know how this came about, but Linux Mint makes texlive a "hard" dependency... will try the `equivs` package.

Comment: `equivs` worked great. I created version 9999 of `texlive-base-bin`, overriding the original "dummy" package of the same name (provided by `texlive-binaries`), and installed `vim-latexsuite` without any troubles.

Answer (score 3):

The following will remove the dependancy from a .deb file, in this case removing libperl5.20 dependancy from freeradius:

```
dpkg-deb -x freeradius_2.2.5+dfsg-0.2+deb8u1_amd64.deb freeradius
dpkg-deb -e freeradius_2.2.5+dfsg-0.2+deb8u1_amd64.deb freeradius/DEBIAN
sed -i  -e 's/, libperl5.20 (>= 5.20.2)//g' freeradius/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b freeradius freeradius_2.2.5+dfsg-0.2+deb8u1_amd64.deb
```

This allows you to install the package without apt knowing the dependency exists.

If you are manually installing specific versions of packages then you might also want to stop `apt-get upgrade` from upgrading the package in the future:

```
apt-mark hold freeradius
```

Comment: I wish there was something more robust, but this is the only solution that worked. Life saver!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--nodeps` flag on dpkg , which should install the package with no dependancies at all.

```
   --ignore-depends=package,...
          Ignore  dependency-checking for specified packages (actu-
          ally, checking is performed, but only warnings about con-
          flicts are given, nothing else)
```

There's a [very similar question on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies) which is worth looking at as well

Comment: Uh... no such thing? (At least not on the Linux Mint 12 box I have here.)

Comment: hm, i seem to have made a mistake - its for dpkg, not apt-get - edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: That's something that confuses me to no end with the Debian derivates: The multitude of package manager interfaces. I assume that there are no tripfalls involved when mixing them? Or would I have to stick to one of them?

Comment: everything is based off dpkg, essentially, apt and aptitude are front ends to that, and there's front ends for apt and aptitude. dpkg is usually used when you want to install packages off a .deb file. I tend to stick to apt-get and dpkg for most part myself. Mixing the 'default' debian flavoured package managers should usually be reasonablys safe

Comment: That makes your answer my preferred solution for my *actual* problem, since nothing depends on vim-latexsuite in turn. However, this solution doesn't mark "texlive" as being *present*, it merely keeps vim-latexsuite from asking for it. As such, Daniel's answer better fits the title of the question. Checkmark goes to him, kudos go to you. ;-)