# How can I perform a full texlive installation (all packages) in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, latex, packages

Title say it all, how can I install texlive and all the packages so I can run tex2pdf on CentOS? I'm rather used to Ubuntu and all this yum business is driving me nuts.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have made some ground, currently trying a web-install from http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html.

Comment: That, indeed, is the best way to go in my experience. You might want to figure out how to tell `yum` that TeXLive *is* actually installed, in some way, [as I did for apt](http://superuser.com/questions/416551/how-to-tell-apt-that-dependencies-are-resolved-manually).

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo yum install texlive-*
```

Running the above gave me the following output. Is that what you're looking for? It looks like everything.

> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ========================================================================================================================  Package                                   Arch             Version
>   Repository         Size
>   ======================================================================================================================== Installing:  texlive-afm                               i686
>   2007-57.el6_2                       base               47 k 
>   texlive-context                           i686
>   2007-57.el6_2                       base               58 k 
>   texlive-dviutils                          i686
>   2007-57.el6_2                       base              191 k 
>   texlive-east-asian                        i686
>   2007-57.el6_2                       base              355 k 
>   texlive-texmf-afm                         noarch           2007-38.el6
>   base              4.5 M  texlive-texmf-context
>   noarch           2007-38.el6                         base
>   2.7 M  texlive-texmf-doc                         noarch           2007-38.el6                         base              175 M 
>   texlive-texmf-east-asian                  noarch           2007-38.el6
>   base              564 k  texlive-texmf-errata-afm
>   noarch           2007-7.1.el6                        base
>   5.4 k  texlive-texmf-errata-context              noarch           2007-7.1.el6                        base              4.7 k 
>   texlive-texmf-errata-doc                  noarch
>   2007-7.1.el6                        base              5.9 k 
>   texlive-texmf-errata-east-asian           noarch
>   2007-7.1.el6                        base              5.6 k 
>   texlive-texmf-errata-xetex                noarch
>   2007-7.1.el6                        base              4.7 k 
>   texlive-texmf-xetex                       noarch           2007-38.el6
>   base              137 k  texlive-xetex
>   i686             2007-57.el6_2                       base
>   2.1 M Installing for dependencies:  compat-readline5                          i686             5.2-17.1.el6                        base
>   128 k  dvipdfm                                   i686
>   0.13.2d-41.1.el6                    base              266 k  dvipdfmx                                  i686             0-0.31.20090708cvs.el6              base
>   336 k  dvipng                                    i686
>   1.11-3.2.el6                        base               95 k  gd                                        i686             2.0.35-11.el6                       base
>   141 k  libpaper                                  i686
>   1.1.23-6.1.el6                      base               34 k  mendexk                                   i686             2.6e-57.el6_2                       base
>   48 k  perl-PDF-Reuse                            noarch
>   0.35-3.el6                          base               89 k  ruby                                      i686             1.8.7.352-13.el6                    updates
>   534 k  ruby-libs                                 i686
>   1.8.7.352-13.el6                    updates           1.6 M  t1lib                                     i686             5.1.2-6.el6_2.1                     base
>   152 k  teckit                                    i686
>   2.5.1-4.1.el6                       base              242 k  xdvipdfmx                                 i686             0.4-5.1.el6                         base
>   479 k
>
> Transaction Summary
>   ======================================================================================================================== Install      28 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 190 M Installed size: 344 M Is this ok [y/N]: n

Comment: I had to quote the the argument glob on zsh: `yum install 'texlive-*'`

Comment: I tried that (with AlmaLinux) and it was far from comprehensive, many packages were missing. I am used to `texlive-full` in Debian-like distro, it does not compete. The `install-tl` method listed below saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

This is really the biggest of failure of CentOS/Fedora.  For a while, Fedora had a similarly insane setup where a working texlive install would be, by count, more than half of the total packages installed on a system.  `</soapbox>`

I offer a partial and albeit somewhat hacky solution, similar to @DevSolar 's solution for apt. It half works, perhaps someone else with this problem can figure out what's going on and fix it.

- First step is to install TexLive manually : http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
- Second, uninstall all your (ancient) texlive-* packages, as appropriate for you: `yum uninstall texlive*`
- Third, use my sloppy script to create two trickly little rpms that claim to "provide" all the rpm packages that yum knows about: https://gist.github.com/tesch1/444d09b62bd49756c59ae89b4b9244c9
- Fourth, install those custom rpms.  Now you should be able to install packages that depend on texlive* packages.

There is some problem with the rpms, and I dont understand RPM well enough to fix it:  It seems to work ok for (allow installation of) other packages that depend on the .noarch texlive packages, but not packages that depend on the texlive arch-specific packages... go figure.  Anyway, it got me working productively again, maybe it'll help someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

I eschewed the package manager in order to get a more recent version of texlive.

TUG gives instructions for [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). They give details for specific cases, such as an unattended install or the need to use proxies, but here's the vanilla:

1. Download the installation according to your OS:
   [install-tl-windows.exe](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe) for Windows, [install-tl-unx.tar.gz](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) for Linux.
2. After unpacking the archive, change to the resulting install-tl-* subdirectory. Then `perl install-tl`

Comment: [This askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/922611/117018) shows how to do the `install-tl`'s download in one step and its installation in another (in case the lengthy installation fails and needs to be repeated).