# Tell dpkg that a dependency is installed when it is not

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt, dpkg

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux and it is impossible to install linux-libc-dev but all of the functionality is actually there. In practice its dependency is met. I need to convince DPKG of this so that I can install things, because I don't feel like running dpkg --no-deps or whatever for every package from now on. I have seen this question "[How to tell apt that dependencies are resolved manually?](https://superuser.com/questions/416551/how-to-tell-apt-that-dependencies-are-resolved-manually)", however all of the answers say "this is a bad idea". I am interested in trying the bad idea anyway and would like to know if anyone knows how to do it. If it blows up my WSL install I'll just redo it; I don't care.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly what you want, but does `dpkg --force-depends ...` help? It will turn dependency errors into warnings, so you can install whatever you like ...

Comment: That might do it, is there any way to get apt to do this as well?

Comment: This, combined with apt-get download, worked for me. If you put it in an answer below I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the package with `apt-get download` (or even directly from the package server, that also works), then use

```
dpkg --force-depends ...
```

That will turn dependency errors into warnings, so you can install whatever you like ...